# Bachelier model in terms of normal distribution to simulate price

Tags: bachelier

Bachelier Model is $dS_t = rdt + dW_t$ and can also write to $S_t = S_0 + W_t$
How can write $W_t$ in terms of normal distribution?[image]

Basically I want to simulated the underlying asset in the Bachelier Model.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I adjusted your function slightly:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def terminal_value(S0, sigma, M):
    S = np.zeros(M)
    S[0] = S0
    for i in range(1, M):
        S[i] = S[i-1] + sigma * np.random.standard_normal() * np.sqrt(1/M)
    return S

for i in range(10):
    series = terminal_value(100, 10, 100)
    plt.plot(series)
```

It works now and produces the following:

[image: paths]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not asking about coding. I am not sure whether the formula that I used to produce St is correct or not. I want to ask about how to write St's formula in terms of normal distribution.

Comment: Your code is correct. $\sigma W_t$ *is* normally distributed, with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2 t$

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user50317: What StackG is implying is that, if you want to simulate the continuous trajectory of $W$ from time $t$ to time $t+\triangle t$, then a good discrete approximation is  N(0, $\triangle t$).

Comment: @markleeds it is more than just a good approximation, as in this case this Euler-Maruyama update is a sample from the exact distribution, and so has no bias.

Comment: By the way, $S_t$ is also normally distributed... $S_t \sim \mathbb{N}(S_0, \sigma^2 t)$

Comment: oliversm: just to make sure I follow ( sde is not my thing ),  are you saying that the size of $\triangle t$ is irrelevant and it's unbiased regardless of small or large $\triangle t$ is ? thanks.

Comment: That is correct... if you have two normal distributions each with variance $0.5 t$, or ten normal distributions each with variance $0.1 t$, in either case the sum of those normals will have variance $t$ (since variance is additive)

Comment: @StackG: That makes sense. But, since we would generate normal's at steps of $\triangle t$, wouldn't the path ( i.e. trajectory ) in the normal case  be a lot choppier than a true brownian motion path. I guess I'm not understanding the concept of unbiasedness because the places in between the normally distributed points are going to be straight lines until they the next $\triangle t$ is reached. So, wouldn't $\triangle t$ have to get smaller and smaller in order for convergence to happen ? And so how can the choppy trajectory be unbiased. Thanks.

Comment: You can test this yourself in Python, but if I understand your question then no, doing it in a single step or doing it in 10 small steps will generate the same amount of variance at expiry